# downloading resourses from URL java

Tags: java, url

I have a list of Links that's points to server repository location, Links represents some resourses that includes images, xml,txt,csv (each of different sizes) files but the problem i am facing is that when i download files all downloaded files got same file size.

```
List<String> Links;//list of links dynamically populated 
for(String link:Links)
{
    int i=link.lastIndexOf("/");
    String temp=link.substring(0, i);
    String contentname = temp.substring(temp.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    String filePath = tempFolderPath + "\\" + contentname;
    URL url = new URL(link);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    InputStream is = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); 
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath)); 
        int inByte;
        while((inByte = is.read()) != -1) 
            fos.write(inByte);
        is.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            is.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

where links are direct access to the resourses "//localhost:8090/documents/11234/13935/abc.txt"

Comment: what is in the downloaded files?  actual content?  something else?

Comment: if i open downloaded images of type jpg,png it does not open and other files contain data but not complete data.

Comment: are you getting exceptions?

Comment: no i am file not getting any exception all the files that i have downloaded of same size that is 26k

Comment: do you control the server as well?  how is the server configured?

Comment: code that i have mentioned  above is the part of web service and from that web service i am accessing Liferay repository contents .

Answer (score -1):

Use a BufferedInputStream instead of a DataInputStream which is solely intended for java object streams.

---

```
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream(); 
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    Files.copy(is, new File(filePath)); 
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

As problems still exist:

For downloading HTML I did an extra thing: I faked being a browser.

```
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(),
                StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)), true);
        // We use the standard for our own headers: Latin-1 and "\r\n".

        // Set our own headers, gotten from Firefox TamperData plugin.
        out.print("GET " + pageURL.getPath() + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        out.print("Host: " + pageURL.getHost() + "\r\n");
        out.print("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0\r\n");
        out.print("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n");
        out.print("Accept-Language: eo,de-de;q=0.8,de;q=0.6,en-us;q=0.4,en;q=0.2\r\n");
        out.print("\r\n");
        out.flush();
```

Most important is to inspect the resulting file.

Comment: i also use BufferedInputStream but no success